# Access Struct Array Data in Arduino

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, arduino

I'm struggling to create and access data stored in a struct array on my Arduino Uno.

I'm not too familiar with C++/Arduino but in my head the below should work. 
The lights and stuff all work with other code but does not work when trying to change the light with light[i].

Might be something to do with pointers but i'm still unsure of when/where to use them.

```
struct light
{
  byte k;
  byte r;
  byte g;
  byte b;
};

typedef struct light Light;

Light l1;
Light l2;
Light l3;

Light lights[3] = {l1, l2, l3};

void setup() {
    l1 = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    l2 = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    l3 = {0, 0, 0, 0};
}

void loop()
{
    l1 = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    l2 = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    l3 = {0, 0, 0, 0};


    //turn on different light every 3 seconds
    int i;

    if (millis() % 9000 < 3000) {
      i = 0;
    } else if ((millis() % 9000 >= 3000) && (millis() % 9000 < 6000)) {
      i = 1;
    } else {
      i = 2;
    }

    lights[i] = {255, 255,0, 0};

    // if this is uncommented l1 turns red
    //l1 = {255,255,0,0}

    //passes light data to DMX controller (works fine)
    ~turnOnlight(l1)
    ~turnOnLight(l2)
    ~turnOnLight(l3)
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Arduino is actually using C++, not C.

Comment: As for your question, can you please elaborate? What is the problem you have with the code? Do you get errors? Crashes? Unexpected results? Something else? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), if you haven't done that yet.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oops, sorry will edit. new to arduino/c/c++

Comment: If the problem is with pointers, perhaps it is because *there are none*. I see no reason for l1..l3 in this *at all*. Doing `lights[i] = ...` doesn't change the contents of `l1..l3` that `lights[]` was initialized with; it just changes `lights[]`. You can change `lights[]` all you want, but when invoking `~turnOnlight(l1)` the `l1` passed is the same as it was before. So... pass `lights[i]` instead? I.e `~turnOnlight(lights[i])`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm trying to update the data in each of the Lights so that every 3 seconds the a different light turns on. Basically, every three seconds, i will change to either 0, 1, or 2, which I want to use to access the struct in the index i lights array. The code compiles, but the values in l1, l2, l3 do not update

Comment: Are you aware that lights holds a copy of l1, l2 and l3 as you declared and initialized it? That is, your program has 6 independent Light structs, the 3 named ones and the 3 in the array.

Comment: @WhozCraig okay that makes sense. The reason i have l1,l2,l3 is because that is how the DMX code accesses them. So maybe the array needs to be initialised with the address of l1,l2,l3 such as `Light lights[3] = {&l1,&l2, &l3}`. Would this be correct?

Comment: @JordanE That would not even compile. You probably want your array to point to respective lights, then you would need `Light* lights[3] = {&l1,&l2, &l3}` and when accesing the array member you have to dereference the pointer like this `*lights[i] = {255, 255,0, 0};`

Comment: @vasek ahh yep, I understand now! thanks for the patience and clarification everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want your array to point to respective lights, then you would need Light* lights[3] = {&l1,&l2, &l3} and when accesing the array member you have to dereference the pointer like this *lights[i] = {255, 255,0, 0};